# Random number distribution is uneven / non uniform

Tags: c#, .net, random

I have noticed a strange issue with the random number generation in c#, it looks like sets (patterns) are repeated a lot more often than you would expect.

I'm writing a mechanism that generates activation codes, a series of 7 numbers (range 0-29).
Doing the math, there should be 30^7 (22billion) possible combinations of activation codes. Based on this it should be extremely unlikely to get a duplicate activation code before the 1 billionth code is generated. However running my test, I start getting duplicate codes after about 60,000 iteration, which is very surprising. I have also tried using RNGCryptoServiceProvider with similar results, I get duplicates at about 100,000 iterations.

I would really like to know if this is a bug/limitation of the random number generation in .Net or if I'm doing something wrong.

The following code is a test to validate the uniqueness of the generated codes:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        RandomActivationCode(rand, true);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Press enter");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void RandomActivationCode(Random randomGenerator)
    {
        var maxItems = 11000000;
        var list = new List<string>(maxItems);
        var activationCodes = new HashSet<string>(list);
        activationCodes.Clear();
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxItems; ++i)
        {
            string activationCode = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; ++j)
            {
                activationCode += randomGenerator.Next(0,30) + "-";
            }
            if (activationCodes.Contains(activationCode))
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Code: " + activationCode);
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Duplicate at iteration: " + i.ToString("##,#"));
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Press enter");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Out.WriteLine();
                Console.Out.WriteLine();
            }
            else
            {
                activationCodes.Add(activationCode);
            }
            if (i % 100000 == 0)
            {

                Console.Out.WriteLine("Iteration: " + i.ToString("##,#"));
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Time elapsed: " + (DateTime.Now - start));
            }

        }
    }
```

My workaround is to use 10 number activation codes, which means that the test runs without any duplicate values being generated. The test runs up to 11 million iterations (after which point it runs out of memory).

Comment: `30^7 (22billion) possible combinations` ... `extremely unlikely to get a duplicate [...]before the 1 billionth code...` - birthday paradox?

Comment: Why do you generate activation codes randomly? Even then, you still have to store them, so you could check the activation. So you can always check if one already exists and if yes, then generate new.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd agreed, I mentioned this in my post that im using 10 character activation codes as a work around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not at all surprising; this is exactly what you should expect. Your belief that it should take a long time to generate duplicates when the space of possibilities is large is simply false, so **stop believing that**. Start believing the truth: that if there are n possible codes then you should start getting duplicates at about the square root of n codes generated, which is about 150 thousand if n is 22 billion.

Think about it this way: by the time you have generated root-n codes, most of them have had roughly a root-n-in-n chance to have a collision. Multiply root-n by roughly root-n-in-n, and you get... roughly 100% chance of collision.

That is of course not a rigorous argument, but it should give you the right intution, to replace your faulty belief. If that argument is unconvincing then you might want to read my article on the subject:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions.aspx

If you want to generate a *unique* code then *generate a GUID*; that's what they're for. **Note that a GUID is not guaranteed to be random, it is only guaranteed to be unique**.

Another choice for generating random *seeming* codes that are not actually random at all, but are unique, is to generate the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, ... as many as you want, and then use the multiplicative inverse technique to make a random-looking unique encoding of those numbers. See http://ericlippert.com/2013/11/14/a-practical-use-of-multiplicative-inverses/ for details.

Comment: Its important that the code is random, so that it is cryptographically secure. Collision is less of an issue, but undesirable if it occurs. I have considered workaround such as querying the database and recreating an activation code if there is a collision.

Comment: @setebos: You say "cryptographically secure" -- secure *against what attack*?

Comment: __stop believing that__ in bold - I think you can put that on a T-shirt ;-)

Comment: @EricLippert you can use the activation code to register on a website, so you want to avoid someone guessing the activation code for a user.

Comment: @setebos: Then 22 billion codes is already far too few. If you have a billion users then one in every 22 codes is good!

Comment: @EricLippert luckily the userbase is much smaller than that, and i have fudged the number slightly to emphasise my point, also we use two factor authentication, so it should make interception a lot more difficult. However, based on your explanation which I dont fully understand yet, I would say we need a 12 character code.

Comment: @setebos: You're the one who said that you expected to be able to generate a billion codes without repetition; I assumed that that was the number of codes you needed. I would consider taking a different approach. Consider: take the user name and a randomly generated salt. Sign it with your private key and hash the result. That's the code. A user gives you their name and the code; you look up the salt and repeat the encryption; if the hashes match then you know the user is authenticated. If two users happen to get the same hash (or same salt), who cares?

Comment: @EricLippert sorry that was just bad maths, i was struggling to understand why i was getting collisions so early. I was using 1 billion as an example of when I thought collision would be likely or at least plausible...

Comment: @setebos: I note that there is a possible chosen-plaintext attack against this scheme but it seems implausible that an attacker could actually derive details of your private key by manipulating their user name, particularly in the presence of a random salt.

Comment: Personally I'd avoid using crypto for that in favour of generating random 128 bit tokens and matching them to the user via the database since it avoid the troubles of key management (preferably storing the hash of the token instead of the token, so an attacker who can read the db can't register an account, but that's a rather minor concern) If you go the crypto route, one approach is using HMAC with a secret key as key input and the email address as message. Not sure what Eric meant precisely by "Sign it with your private key and hash the result.", but it sounds weird.